# Info repeatedly getting recorded in DB

Tags: c#, sql

[image]I have a Form where I am inserting a record into the database. There are two tables, table_1 is called `members`, and table_2 is called `Amount`.

I am using two SQL `INSERT` statements to send records to database , because that’s the way I have figured out -- there might be other ways, which I don’t know.

When I insert the record I get a message that it is inserted successfully, but when I check the database the inserted record replaces the one present , so I have last record in the DB repeated several times. Please assist.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CemiyetAidatSistem
{
    public partial class AddMember : Form
    {
        public AddMember()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=My-PC\\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=FredericiaDernek;Integrated Security=True");

        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string Sql = "INSERT INTO Uyeleri ( dID, FullName, Address, Mobile, Email, Comments ) VALUES ('" + txtdID.Text + "', '" + txtAdiSoyadi.Text + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtMobile.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtComments.Text + "')";
            cmd.CommandText = Sql;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            Sql = "INSERT INTO Aidat (dID Year, Amount ) VALUES ('"+ txtdID.Text +"','" + txtYear.Text + "','" + txtAmount.Text + "')";
            cmd.CommandText = Sql;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this.Controls[i] is TextBox)
                {
                    this.Controls[i].Text = "";
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Data Added Scuessfully");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Look at your Table Design are there primary keys, also the ID's that you are inserting , Change your query / Insert statements to utilize SQL Paramaters, you are setting yourself up for SQL Injection.. also do you have a schema you can show of both tables.. perhaps a screen shot you could paste to show the Table Definition..? also don't assume that the Inserts are working always try wrapping Try{}Catch around both of your ExecuteNonQuery commands..

Comment: So I have an image of the table and structure, I hopw it will give an overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rewritten your code to correct errors and bad practices

```
string connString = "Data Source=My-PC\\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=FredericiaDernek;Integrated Security=True";

private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        con.Open();
        string Sql = "INSERT INTO Uyeleri (dID, FullName, Address, Mobile, Email, Comments ) " + 
                     "VALUES (@id, @name, @address, @mobile, @email, @comments");
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtdID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtAdiSoyadi.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtMobile.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", txtComments.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Sql = "INSERT INTO Aidat (dID, [Year], Amount ) VALUES " + 
                  "(@id, @year, @amount)";
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.CommandText = Sql;  // <- missing this in the previous version.....
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtdID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtYear.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", txtAmount.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

What I have changed:

- The second insert statement is wrong. Missing a comma between first
  and second column
- Removed the creation of the SqlConnection at the global level
- Added appropriate using statement to dispose the SqlConnection and
  SqlCommand also in case of exceptions
- Used parameters for the two insert statements
- Added square brackets around Year field (Year is a reserved keyword
  in T-SQL)

Creating a SqlConnection at the global level is bad, because you grab system resources and you don't dispose them for the lifetime of your application. And the situation could be out of control in case of exceptions not correctly handled.

Now I have some doubt about your tables. The fields dID (both tables) and Amount are of text type (varchar,nvarchar)?. If they are of numeric type it is necessary to add a conversion before adding the values to the Parameters collection

Comment: Philipp looks like Steve provided a Rock Solid Solution Awesome job @Steve

Comment: Waiting the OP to say something. I think that the OP code could not be used as presented for the obvious error in the second query. Also the OP doesn't show anything about its select statement.

Comment: I've noticed that too.. he mentions his select statement but I am thinking that he meant to say Insert ..but we will have to wait..

Comment: @DJKRAZE also an answer to your comment about the table SCHEMA is critical to give a complete answer.

Comment: I totally agree.. will I guess we will have to wait and see what the OP says.. I also think that his for loop could be better optimized using linq to find the Type of Control

Comment: nice answer....but always write sql code in a try catch so that it can handle exceptions...

Comment: Well Sorry to disappoint you but after applying the solution I still get a double entry of the record inserted removing the first one inserted. I have although provided a image which shows the structure of Form & Tables structure.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. The INSERT statement use columns that doesn't exist in the datatable showed. Do you have translated them? Also the ID column is an Integer and a Primary Key (don't know if it is also an Identity column). However, if these are the tables where you insert your data there should be no way to have two records with the same ID. You should get an exception on Primary Key violation.

Comment: Well Thank you for replying Steve, I have translated the names if you have noticed, there is an ID which is Primary Key and its not visible, but a "Distinct id is also present which is a varChar(50). what happens is the when I insert a new record lets say there is a present, e.g "ftkd01" the I insert a new one "ftkd02" and after inserting this I check the database I see that "ftkd01" exist no more but "ftdk02" is written times two. That is kind of strange Phenomenon

Comment: I have made an error in my previous code. Don't know if this is the problem that you are experiencing. Try with the update above

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest changing your for loop to clear the controls replace this

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    if (this.Controls[i] is TextBox)
    {
        this.Controls[i].Text = "";
    }
}
```

with the following code using linq.

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());
```

keep in mind that **'this'** will refer to the name of your Form

so it would be

```
(YourWinFormsName).Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());
```